# Cannot post to server with token authentication system

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, ember.js, jwt

I am building an Ember app with a Node back end.  I am attempting to implement a JWT authentication system and also have Ember simple auth installed, but it when I try submit the form with credentials that are already saved in the server I get back the error message: Cannot POST /sessions/create  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my Ember authenticator code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'simple-auth/authenticators/base';
export default Base.extend({
    tokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/sessions/create',
    restore: function(data) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    },

    authenticate: function(options) {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: this.tokenEndpoint,
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    username: options.identification,
                    password: options.password
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function(response) {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    resolve({
                        token: response.id_token
                    });
                });
            }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                var response = xhr.responseText;
                Ember.run(function() {
                    reject(response);
                });
            });
        });
    },

    invalidate: function() {
        console.log('invalidate...');
        return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
    }
});
```

Here is my Ember authorizer code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';
export default Base.extend({
    authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
        var accessToken = this.get('session.content.secure.token');
        if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my code from the Node server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    _       = require('lodash'),
    config  = require('./config'),
    jwt     = require('jsonwebtoken');

var app = module.exports = express.Router();

// XXX: This should be a database of users :).
var users = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'gonto',
  password: 'gonto'
}];

function createToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign(_.omit(user, 'password'), config.secret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });
}

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).send("You must send the username and the password");
  }
  if (_.find(users, {username: req.body.username})) {
   return res.status(400).send("A user with that username already exists");
  }

  var profile = _.pick(req.body, 'username', 'password', 'extra');
  profile.id = _.max(users, 'id').id + 1;

  users.push(profile);

  res.status(201).send({
    id_token: createToken(profile)
  });
});

app.post('/sessions/create', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).send("You must send the username and the password");
  }

  var user = _.find(users, {username: req.body.username});
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).send("The username or password don't match");
  }

  if (user.password !== req.body.password) {
    return res.status(401).send("The username or password don't match");
  }

  res.status(201).send({
    id_token: createToken(user)
  });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in console (client or server)? If you add console.log to sessions create app.post in node.js does it get loggged to console?